# How to correlate Zabbix triggers to actions? I can't find an action for a trigger yet I'm getting emails.

Tags: zabbix

I'm taking over a legacy Zabbix instance and there are triggers defined in a template that are sending emails without an action tied to them. For example, the template has triggers for "Free disk space less than 40%", but we don't have any actions defined for this. How/why is Zabbix sending emails for this without an action, and bonus points if you know how to turn this off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions are not necessarily "tied to triggers". Actions have conditions that can be as narrow as "if this trigger fires", and as broad as "match anything". To identify the action with confidence, add `{ACTION.ID}` in the message body for all of them.

If you do that and emails don't get action ID, it might be a different Zabbix instance even - check email headers to find out where it originated from.

Comment: Thanks, there are lots of fuzzy matching errors in our actions it turns out.